# How to style different the last item of list in react native?

Tags: react-native, styling

I am rendering list item by for loop.
what i need is to give margin Top: 10 to every element except last element.

Comment: provide some code pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

In case you are using JSS, you can do:

```
'ul > li:not(:last-child)': {
  marginTop: 10;
}
```